# Play! framework: not found: value in template

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, template-engine

I want to add a title in template

```
@()
@(title: String)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>@title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

but I see the error:

```
Compilation error
not found: value title
```

in routes

```
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
```

controller

```
public class HomeController extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        return ok(views.html.index.render());
    }
}
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: You have to provide title as string in the controller like: Ok("Some string")

Comment: Please provide full code sample you struggling with

Comment: when i do in routes: controllers.HomeController.index(title: String), and in controller: public Result index(String title){...}, i see this error too.

Comment: remove first line from template code, it does not make any sense to have it and put value for title when you call .render method, ...reder("SomeTitle)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me

Comment: feel free to put answer against your question